# Cannot sign data using eth_signTypedData_v3 in coinbase wallet but can in every other dapp wallet?

Tags: wallets, dapps, signature

Signing data worked in trustwallet, metamask, opera wallet. But not in coinbase using walletlink.

Using eth_signTypedData_v3 - when sent to coinbase wallet via walletlink the error Cannot read property 'EIP712Domain' of undefined is returned.

```
   const domain = [
      { name: "name", type: "string" },
      { name: "version", type: "string" },
      { name: "chainId", type: "uint256" },
      { name: "verifyingContract", type: "address" },
      { name: "salt", type: "bytes32" },
    ];
```

```
  const data = JSON.stringify({
      types: {
        EIP712Domain: domain,
        Listing: Listing,
      },
      primaryType: "Listing",
      domain: domainData,
      message: message,
    });
 
    const signedData = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      web3.currentProvider.sendAsync(
        {
          method: "eth_signTypedData_v3",
          params: [account, data],
          from: account,
        },
```

returns the error:

```
web3.saga.tsx:720 TypeError: Cannot read property 'EIP712Domain' of undefined
    at Object.findTypeDependencies (index.js:149)
    at Object.encodeType (index.js:127)
    at Object.hashType (index.js:179)
    at Object.encodeData (index.js:42)
    at Object.hashStruct (index.js:168)
    at Object.hash (index.js:208)
    at Object.hashForSignTypedData_v3 (index.js:225)
    at WalletLinkProvider._eth_signTypedData_v3 (WalletLinkProvider.js:449)
    at WalletLinkProvider._handleAsynchronousMethods (WalletLinkProvider.js:235)
    at WalletLinkProvider.js:186
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at WalletLinkProvider._sendRequestAsync (WalletLinkProvider.js:165)
    at WalletLinkProvider.sendAsync (WalletLinkProvider.js:112)
```

Yet in walletlink's code it has:

```
  async _eth_signTypedData_v3(params) {
        this._requireAuthorization();
        const address = util_1.ensureAddressString(params[0]);
        const typedData = params[1];
        this._ensureKnownAddress(address);
        const message = eth_eip712_util_1.default.hashForSignTypedData_v3({ data: typedData });
        const typedDataJson = JSON.stringify(typedData, null, 2);
        return this._signEthereumMessage(message, address, false, typedDataJson);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue was JSON.stringify, as walletlink sanitizes the data.

```
 const data = JSON.stringify({
      types: {
        EIP712Domain: domain,
        Listing: Listing,
      },
      primaryType: "Listing",
      domain: domainData,
      message: message,
    });
```

to

```
 const data = {
      types: {
        EIP712Domain: domain,
        Listing: Listing,
      },
      primaryType: "Listing",
      domain: domainData,
      message: message,
    };
```

fixed it.